# Ghost: newest post with specific tag on the front page

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I am developing a Ghost template for my blog. And  I want to see on the front page only one newest post from posts with specific tag (eg "news").

Is it possible to filter posts by tag in `foreach` loop?

Any other solution? (the first thing that comes to mind is some trick with custom template `tag-news.hbs` and URL rewriting)

Comment: +1 - i want to get just 2 posts on first page (`home.hbs`, one featured and the latest), but more posts on subsequent `index.hbs` pages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can definitely filter posts by tag using the `{{has}}` helper:

```
{{#foreach posts}}
  {{#has tag="news"}}
      {{> post}}
  {{/has}}
{{/foreach}}
```

You could add this code to a `home.hbs` file and it would only be used on your homepage.

I'm not sure of the best way to limit it to one post if you want other list pages to have more than one post though. You may have to write a custom helper.

You do have access to an `@index` variable, but if the first post with 'news' is the third post, `@index` will be `2` because it increments with the outer `foreach` loop.

Soon you should be able to use the api: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/%5BWIP%5D-API-Documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sad, but seems like this API will not have flexible requests features like `/ghost/api/v0.1/posts/tag/:id` etc.

I think best workaround at this time is to play with nginx url rewriting.

Answer (score 5):

After having a read of the lengthy discussion [GitHub Ghost Issue: Query (get) helper #4439](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/4439) recently closed, great news - helpers and filters are being added to [Public API v1](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/milestones/Public%20API%20v1)!

[The {{#get}} helper #5619](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/pull/5619) has just been merged to master (still unstable), so the solution:

```
{{#get "posts" featured="true" as |featured|}}
  {{#foreach featured}}
    ...
  {{/foreach}}
 {{/get}}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I still get posts without being featured

Answer (score 4):

I've created a little hack for Ghost. It adds {{by_tag}} helper to the theme templates

1. Create helpers.js in ghost directory with code [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/ofstudio/e13276a9c587ecd41a95)
2. Add **first line** to your config.js: `require('./helpers')();`
3. Restart ghost

#### {{#by_tag}} Helper

Select posts by tag. Optional `limit` parameter.

Example:

```
 {{#by_tag 'dev'}}
     {{#foreach posts}}
         {{title}}
         {{content}}
     {{/foreach}}
 {{/by_tag}}

 {{#by_tag 'music' limit=3}}
    {{#foreach posts}}
         {{title}}
         {{content}}
     {{/foreach}}
 {{/by_tag}}
```

#### {{#node_env}} Helper

Example:

```
{{#node_env production}}
     ...production only 
{{/node_env}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little useful info, if you want to add featured posts, this is how:

```
{{#get "posts" filter="featured:true" as |featured| }}
  <ol>
  {{#foreach featured}}
    <li><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></li>
  {{/foreach}}
  </ol>
{{/get}}
```

To get a rough idea of what more you can do, visit the official [GitHub](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/4439)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In `index.hbs`:

```
    <div class="post-feed">
      {{#foreach posts}}
          {{^has tag="videos"}}
            {{! this block will not show posts tagged videos }}
            {{> "post-card"}}
          {{/has}}
      {{/foreach}}
    </div>
```

In `tag-videos.hbs`:

```
    <div class="post-feed">
        {{#foreach posts}}
            {{#has tag="videos"}}
              {{! this block will show posts tagged videos }}
              {{> "post-card"}}
            {{/has}}
        {{/foreach}}
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!